# How can we maintain check box state in when we move to next page in pageblock table?

Tags: apex, visualforce

We have a code with next and previous button in the VF page.When a user click on the check box and then click on next or previous buttons the state of checkbox on the records should be maintained?

What would be the best possible approach for that to deal it .
To go with Apex functions or To go with javascript functionality to implement this.
Thanks In Advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i dont know whether are you are facing this problem in pagination or any other bussiness use case.

But in standard pagination if you use **StandardSetController** check-boxes don’t maintain state if you check one and then go to the next page.

Inorder to solve this problem you have to implement custom Iterator.

Following posts will explain you detail

http://salesforcehelpinghands.blogspot.sg/2012/10/pagination-with-maintaing-state-of.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823107/how-to-find-out-which-checkboxes-have-been-selected-on-the-next-page-in-visualfo/14825189#14825189